# Why does GSheet's "find" not find my blank cells even though ISBLANK() finds them?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, find-replace

I have the following problem: When I type "^\s*$" into GSheet's "find" it does not find my blank cells even though ISBLANK() finds them. I need to find and replace the blank cells with "NA". Help would be greatly appreciated!

This is an excerpt of my table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EajCPW68UXc8kgeqfsEoxgTBuLbccdAnnj6tZOSntM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Is there any specific purpose why you would want to utilize `regex`?

Comment: I'm not using regex. I'm using the find (and replace) box.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=REGEXMATCH(C5, "^$")
```

---

```
^$
```

Comment: Thanks! But that just does the same as my ISBLANK() function. What I would like to do is use the find and replace box to replace all my blank cells with NAs. (And I only used the ISBLANK() function to show that it finds the empty cells while find and replace does somehow not.)

Comment: Or in case you meant to suggest I type "^$" into the find and replace box: That doesn't seem to work either, unfortunately!

Comment: I could work around it creating new columns with IF and ISBLANK but it would be really great to know if there is a way to make find and replace work. It worked in other sheets in the same circumstances but then sometimes it doesn't, it's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Apps Script code. This should get you started.

```
function replaceBlank() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,2, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var rangeval = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRow()-1; i++) {
    Logger.log(rangeval[i]);
    if (rangeval[i].concat() == ",") {
    rangeval[i].splice(0,2,"NA","NA");
    sheet.getRange(i+2,2,1,2).setValues([rangeval[i]]);
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

The way this code works is that it will iterate through columns B and C and once it detects that the current row is blank, it will set the value NA as defined on `rangeval[i].splice(0,2,"NA","NA");`

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Diego :) I will look into Apps Script, seems interesting! Any idea why the normal find and replace box does not work for my spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this just in case anyone bumps into this issue.

What you need to do is

1. While in the Find and Replace box, find the "Search using regular expressions" option. The "Match case" option will automatically be selected.
2. In the Find box type in "^s*$" without the "" and you should be able to see those empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [documented "Find and Replace" feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?sjid=16705828979607302370-EU#) should work with the `^s*$` regular expression on blank cells too, **it does not indeed**. Neither it works with `\s*` in conjunction with the "Match entire cell contents" flag.

I found a reasonable explanation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/217248400/replacing-empty-cells-via-find-and-replace-not-working?hl=en). The author suggests numbers formatting as "plain text" before "Find and Replace". Really it works and it is easy, because scripting is NOT required. So your steps can be as follows:

- format numbers as "plain text" for [the range in use](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EajCPW68UXc8kgeqfsEoxgTBuLbccdAnnj6tZOSntM/edit#gid=0&range=B2:C36)
- make replacements using the "canonical" regex `^\s*$` in "Find and Replace" dialog
- format numbers back to "Auto" for the above range